# Handle DB disconnections with Q Promises

Tags: node.js, mongodb, q

I'm building a `node.js` app that talks to `MongoDb` using `Q` promises. I'm trying to make it more fault tolerant - so that if MongoDb server goes down - my app detects it and attempts reconnect

the connection is initialized as

```
this.db = Q.nfcall(Mongodb.connect.bind(Mongodb), config.mongoServer).catch(function(){
 console.log('could not connect..');
});
```

and then occasional reads or writes are made chaining no to `this.db` promise

```
this.db
    .then(function(db) {
      var collection = db.collection(pair);
      return Q.nfcall(collection.mapReduce.bind(collection), map, reduce, { out: { inline: 1 }, query: query });
    });
```

if MongoDb server goes down after connection promise is fulfilled - it never goes into `catch` clause. and even if I add another `catch` to further promises no disconnection error is cought

Are there any suggestions?